# Does UIPickerView's component width adjust manually?

Tags: objective-c

I made the UIPickerView and added to viewcontroller'view.

I adjusted pickerview'width manually.

As you look at the picture, not matches between component's contents width and component width, and

pickerview's width and components width.

Is there a method like UILabel's sizeToFit?

```
expected code is :
    - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
        switch(component) {
            [pickerView.label sizeToFit];
        }
    }


================= Following is mycode ====================================================
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)] autorelease];
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];


    activities = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"sleeping", @"eating", @"working", @"studying", @"walking", @"thinking", @"considering", @"testing", @"talking", nil];
    feelings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"awesome", @"sad", @"happy", nil];

}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    switch(component) {
        case 0: return 100;
        case 1: return 200;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try my solution..i have never set the width & height of each component...UIPickerview maintain itself...so i don't have to worry about this....try this just Comment the whole method called "widthForComponent"  and make sure you have used all these Picker methods propely.."numberOfComponentsInPickerView","numberOfRowsInComponent" and "titleForRow" then run the project again...let me know it will solved your problem or not

ok now see the following methods are required with uipickerview...you want some code then here it is

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pV didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    // you're code for when user select any item from picker
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{ 
    if(component == 0)
        return [activities count];
    else if(component == 1)
        return [feelings count];
    
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 0)
        return [activities objectAtIndex:row];
    else if(component == 1)
        return [feelings objectAtIndex:row];
    else
           return @"";
}
```

Comment: component and component's contents size is appropriately adjusted?

Comment: Did you tried what i have saide above...?,comment the whole method widthForComponent & run the project

Comment: Each component width and component's contents width was not appropriately adjusted..

Comment: @user1182731 i have noticed one thing in your code at UIPickerview allocation you have given CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200) make it like CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200) width =320 & re run the project...

Comment: @user1182731 here i am give you tutorial for uipickerview Programatically just check it out [UIPickerview Programatically Click Here](http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.in/2011/04/uipickerview-add-it-programmatically_04.html) let me know i have solved your problem or not

Comment: Thanks P R J. your explanation is helpful.